# updating from 4.3 to 4.4.x

Tags: updates, root-access, nexus-4, 4.4-kitkat

I would like to upgrade my current nexus 4 that's already rooted on 4.3 to the latest 4.4.x android, ideally while keeping my root.  Any tips on how to do this?  I've fallen so far behind on the updates that I don't know what's safe anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SuperSU has a maintain root option, and you could always flash a pre rooted stock firmware. XDA developers is probably your best bet. As for ROMS, that's really down to your taste in these things. Kitkat is nice on the Nexus 4 and 4.4.3 is due soon with some bug fixes in place!